# Is there any way to open link in browser and auth with Some Authenicate Service and open the home page

Tags: java, maven, swing, servlets, java-8

Currently, **In Desktop application**, I have **Help main menu**, when user click on Help it is opening website in browser.

Now we are **planning to Authenicate through some auth service in browser** and once user authenicate success, it will redirect to requested page in browser only.

We are using some third party service(we are not concern about authenicate).

**Website authenicate using auth token.**

So we need to write some logic in Java to provide service url with auth token in header (**GET request**) when user click on Help link by doing this it will bypass the login form and open the requested page.

Can Someone assists on this ?

Once authenicate success open website https://my.abc.com/qa/pg/1  in browser only

With below implementation,i am getting HTML Content

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
   import java.awt.Desktop;

   public class GetRequest {

   private static String GET_URL = "https://my.abc.com/qa/pg/1";
  private static String HEADER_KEY = "X-Auth-Token";
   private static String HEDAER_VALUE = "abcdededndnndd";
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

 //  Desktop.getDesktop().browser("https://my.abc.com/qa/pg/1");
 
  //Creating a HttpClient object
  CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

  //Creating a HttpGet object
  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(GET_URL);
  httpget.setHeader(HEADER_KEY, HEDAER_VALUE);
  
  //Printing the method used
  System.out.println("Request Type: "+httpget.getMethod());

  //Executing the Get request
  HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);
  
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(httpresponse.getEntity().getContent());

  //Printing the status line
  System.out.println(httpresponse.getStatusLine());
  while(sc.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
  }
  httpclient.close();
 }
 }
```

Comment: This is not clear. What do you mean by " in browser only" As in you want to open a web browser that goes to the specific page? It seems like you don't need to use an HttpClient at all then. Do you want to use something from the [Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)) to open a browser?

Comment: yes need to open broswer that will open specific page.  Yes, don't want to use HTTPClient . Need to use some api in java which will take url and header (header will contain auth_token). that auth_token will help to authenicate.

Comment: I don't think you can set the header. Desktop.browse would let you use the browser to open the webpage. You might be able to get away with including url encoded data in the URI. If it is the same browser that you authenticated with, it could just be a matter of going to the webpage. I think a good place to check is with the authentication system provider, they should provide a way. Zoom works with Okta in a similar fashion. It has me open the browser, and login, then the zoom app works.

Comment: ok i agree with you. But don't we have any such library in java which will help us to bypass the login for user . so user will see only website after authenicate.   Or as java 8 allow us to call  javascript . so is there any possibility to have any such api either in java or javascript ?

Comment: Really depends on the authentication framework. I cannot tell which part you need help with. Are you trying to generate the token? Are you trying to make a browser request with the token? If you're using the same browser, then it should just be a matter of authenticating one time.

Comment: Trying to make a browser request with the token